# Using MLPClassifier to build neural network for predicting multiple outputs

Tags: python, neural-network

I am implementing MLPClassifier to try a neural network now, but I am not sure if I can put multiple classes as an output.
Here is my output, as follows:

```
y = array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

What I am trying to do is that I create multiple classes (1,2,3) and want to check if I can predict by using a neural network.

I am not sure if I am on the right path.

Can I only put a single binary output, such [0,1] or can I put multiple outputs that neural network can predict?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.70, random_state=0)
mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs',random_state=0, hidden_layer_sizes[1],alpha=0.001,max_iter=100)
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred=mlp.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try printing out y_pred to show if the classifier is performing a multi-class classification or binary classification? I think it will perform a multi-class classification.

Comment: y_pred    
    array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
It does predict! but I am not sure if it is a right way to do it...